# geoJSON issue invalid GeoJSON object

Tags: php, json, jquery, geojson

I have been trying to get a map (leaflet) to work using MapIT API.

Due to having cross browser issues i cannot use javascript, so i send the info to PHP, PHP gets the info and echo's it back to the function:

Javascript Function:

```
    reqwest({
    url: 'php/ajax.php',
    data: 'switch=mapdetail&mapitid=' + mainid,
    type: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    console.log('passed ' + data);
        var area = new L.GeoJSON(data);
        map.addLayer(area);

        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
        area._iterateLayers(function (layer) {
            if (layer instanceof L.MultiPolygon) {
                layer._iterateLayers(function(layer2) {
                    var new_bounds = layer2.getBounds();
                    bounds.extend(new_bounds.getSouthWest());
                    bounds.extend(new_bounds.getNorthEast());
                });
            }
            if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
                bounds = layer.getBounds();
            }
        }, area);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
});
```

PHP bit:

```
    $mapid = $_POST['mapitid'];

    $thedata = json_encode("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/".mapid.".geojson?simplify_tolerance=0.0001");

    echo thedata;
```

In chrome dev tool I get this as the concole.log (**passed [object XMLHttpRequest]**)

followed by   **Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.**

I am guessing that when the data is returned, it is in some sort of format, but I am unable to see.  Here is the format direct from the site:

http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/2514.geojson?simplify_tolerance=0.0001

**UPDATE EDIT**

Okay, I am now able to see the code in Chrome Dev tool.

New Code:  Javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'php/ajax.php',
    data: 'switch=mapdetail&mapitid=59868',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
        var area = new L.GeoJSON(data);
        map.addLayer(area);

        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
        area._iterateLayers(function (layer) {
            if (layer instanceof L.MultiPolygon) {
                layer._iterateLayers(function(layer2) {
                    var new_bounds = layer2.getBounds();
                    bounds.extend(new_bounds.getSouthWest());
                    bounds.extend(new_bounds.getNorthEast());
                });
            }
            if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
                bounds = layer.getBounds();
            }
        }, area);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
});
```

New PHP:

```
    $mapid = $_POST['mapitid'];

    $thedata = json_encode(file_get_contents("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/".$mapid.".geojson?simplify_tolerance=0.0001"));

    echo $thedata;
```

This is the result:

```
maind id = 59868 { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.487218, 51.524673 ], [ -2.486795, 51.525041 ], [ -2.486594, 51.525985 ], [ -2.487938, 51.526411 ], [ -2.488176, 51.527001 ], [ -2.488628, 51.527298 ], [ -2.490577, 51.527407 ], [ -2.490898, 51.527912 ], [ -2.490764, 51.528206 ], [ -2.490262, 51.528182 ], [ -2.489666, 51.528908 ], [ -2.489246, 51.528918 ], [ -2.488917, 51.529388 ], [ -2.488017, 51.529577 ], [ -2.488903, 51.530538 ], [ -2.490376, 51.531367 ], [ -2.491287, 51.531554 ], [ -2.493421, 51.532469 ], [ -2.493637, 51.532719 ], [ -2.493405, 51.532908 ], [ -2.494018, 51.533586 ], [ -2.493813, 51.533668 ], [ -2.494053, 51.533871 ], [ -2.494691, 51.533692 ], [ -2.494773, 51.533975 ], [ -2.495049, 51.534001 ], [ -2.497023, 51.535115 ], [ -2.497958, 51.535299 ], [ -2.498869, 51.535796 ], [ -2.503044, 51.537171 ], [ -2.505539, 51.538153 ], [ -2.505462, 51.538237 ], [ -2.505768, 51.538400 ], [ -2.506749, 51.538587 ], [ -2.509226, 51.539616 ], [ -2.510444, 51.539373 ], [ -2.516245, 51.537093 ], [ -2.519487, 51.534951 ], [ -2.519770, 51.535112 ], [ -2.518834, 51.535661 ], [ -2.519198, 51.535847 ], [ -2.520104, 51.535281 ], [ -2.520993, 51.535800 ], [ -2.523176, 51.536491 ], [ -2.523705, 51.536050 ], [ -2.524164, 51.535015 ], [ -2.524400, 51.535036 ], [ -2.526038, 51.535597 ], [ -2.528674, 51.537841 ], [ -2.530464, 51.538917 ], [ -2.531443, 51.539279 ], [ -2.533221, 51.540257 ], [ -2.535901, 51.541205 ], [ -2.538733, 51.541768 ], [ -2.540781, 51.542575 ], [ -2.540439, 51.542960 ], [ -2.540130, 51.543027 ], [ -2.540296, 51.543266 ], [ -2.540235, 51.543512 ], [ -2.538972, 51.544100 ], [ -2.538923, 51.544262 ], [ -2.539178, 51.544446 ], [ -2.538498, 51.544564 ], [ -2.538700, 51.544894 ], [ -2.538134, 51.545338 ], [ -2.537945, 51.546351 ], [ -2.537423, 51.546550 ], [ -2.537010, 51.546434 ], [ -2.535453, 51.546656 ], [ -2.533427, 51.547221 ], [ -2.531784, 51.547893 ], [ -2.530263, 51.548780 ], [ -2.529550, 51.549392 ], [ -2.526786, 51.550568 ], [ -2.526825, 51.550845 ], [ -2.526537, 51.551310 ], [ -2.526124, 51.551516 ], [ -2.526089, 51.551792 ], [ -2.525607, 51.552004 ], [ -2.525590, 51.552291 ], [ -2.525345, 51.552302 ], [ -2.525157, 51.552636 ], [ -2.524847, 51.552626 ], [ -2.522527, 51.553966 ], [ -2.522093, 51.553866 ], [ -2.522108, 51.554036 ], [ -2.521753, 51.554080 ], [ -2.521573, 51.554376 ], [ -2.521406, 51.554261 ], [ -2.521062, 51.554511 ], [ -2.520244, 51.554625 ], [ -2.519966, 51.554989 ], [ -2.519671, 51.554849 ], [ -2.517060, 51.555948 ], [ -2.513820, 51.555008 ], [ -2.513911, 51.554328 ], [ -2.513547, 51.554467 ], [ -2.510762, 51.553441 ], [ -2.510516, 51.552596 ], [ -2.509840, 51.551590 ], [ -2.509863, 51.551092 ], [ -2.509555, 51.551038 ], [ -2.509897, 51.550668 ], [ -2.508169, 51.550138 ], [ -2.506176, 51.547936 ], [ -2.506093, 51.548065 ], [ -2.502299, 51.547223 ], [ -2.499534, 51.546897 ], [ -2.496746, 51.547906 ], [ -2.494741, 51.547731 ], [ -2.492722, 51.548296 ], [ -2.490157, 51.549388 ], [ -2.486311, 51.549706 ], [ -2.486413, 51.549090 ], [ -2.486582, 51.548905 ], [ -2.487810, 51.548293 ], [ -2.487170, 51.547647 ], [ -2.487368, 51.546444 ], [ -2.487133, 51.546054 ], [ -2.486300, 51.545561 ], [ -2.485866, 51.544907 ], [ -2.484368, 51.544669 ], [ -2.483687, 51.544353 ], [ -2.483522, 51.544032 ], [ -2.483795, 51.543799 ], [ -2.483713, 51.543623 ], [ -2.482981, 51.543752 ], [ -2.482626, 51.544099 ], [ -2.481342, 51.544563 ], [ -2.481302, 51.544783 ], [ -2.480959, 51.545043 ], [ -2.479887, 51.545650 ], [ -2.479938, 51.545885 ], [ -2.479773, 51.546057 ], [ -2.478910, 51.546471 ], [ -2.477119, 51.546819 ], [ -2.476491, 51.547366 ], [ -2.475257, 51.547549 ], [ -2.474229, 51.547278 ], [ -2.474094, 51.547572 ], [ -2.473668, 51.547696 ], [ -2.472217, 51.547233 ], [ -2.472826, 51.547159 ], [ -2.472977, 51.546795 ], [ -2.472157, 51.546492 ], [ -2.471731, 51.546512 ], [ -2.471710, 51.546357 ], [ -2.470886, 51.546099 ], [ -2.470910, 51.545976 ], [ -2.470226, 51.545737 ], [ -2.469964, 51.545485 ], [ -2.471224, 51.543133 ], [ -2.471587, 51.541971 ], [ -2.472669, 51.541868 ], [ -2.473324, 51.540817 ], [ -2.471415, 51.540643 ], [ -2.471310, 51.539609 ], [ -2.471503, 51.538436 ], [ -2.470360, 51.538025 ], [ -2.469045, 51.537066 ], [ -2.468343, 51.536020 ], [ -2.467243, 51.535040 ], [ -2.466285, 51.534661 ], [ -2.466215, 51.533903 ], [ -2.465796, 51.533080 ], [ -2.464993, 51.532483 ], [ -2.464058, 51.532100 ], [ -2.464207, 51.531620 ], [ -2.465837, 51.531453 ], [ -2.467140, 51.529029 ], [ -2.468394, 51.527443 ], [ -2.471064, 51.524940 ], [ -2.472790, 51.525590 ], [ -2.475423, 51.524617 ], [ -2.475349, 51.524353 ], [ -2.476017, 51.523592 ], [ -2.476650, 51.523409 ], [ -2.478830, 51.523299 ], [ -2.479678, 51.523355 ], [ -2.481826, 51.523899 ], [ -2.484982, 51.524108 ], [ -2.487218, 51.524673 ] ] ] }
```

Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

Comment: Use your debuger to find out the real content of data. It's weird that the response is not the json parsed object but it happens so display the content of data.

Comment: The responses from ajax call is empty when i look at preview within the chrome dev tool.  Would that mean it is echo'ing back nothing?

Comment: I think your problem comes from your php code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you json_encode the URL instead of the content you want.

```
    $thedata = json_encode(file_get_contents("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/".$mapid.".geojson?simplify_tolerance=0.0001"));
```

Moreover It is not a good thing to use the POST method to just provide informations that do not modify the datas stored by the server. A GET request would be ok here.

Comment: How would go about using GET?   I have used $.get in jquery to get some info from another part of this Mapit site.  But this part needs to be done via the server.  Googled but unable to make work any examples there

Comment: I think your right about the PHP.  `XMLHttpRequest
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: function (){a&&a[readyState]==4&&(twoHundo.test(a.status)?b(a):c(a))}
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseBlob: [Exception: DOMException]
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseXML: null
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Using this `$geoJSONurl = json_encode(file_get_contents("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/".mapid.".geojson"));` and echoing it back, i would have thought would give me the same as the putting the url directly, but it comes back with the above and empty

Comment: you can use $.get or specify "get" as type in the $.ajax function.
About what happened to get the responseBlob "DOMException", I need to know what is the result of calling php/ajax.php directly in browser. (don't forget to use $_GET instead of $_POST)

Comment: I have issues with using ajax to get the geoJson directly due to cross browser issues HTTPS to HTTP is blocked.  Which is why i am going the PHP way.  But i cannot get any info from the browser on why it's not getting the info ?

Comment: what I mean is : instead of trying to get a response in Ajax, write the URL you want in your browser and then look at what it sends.
To get some information by your browser you have to use $_GET instead of $_POST and send php/ajax.php?mapid=5 for example.
How and I just saw a typo, i fix it in my answer

Comment: I have checked it works by putting the link direct, and its just a large json subset.  I have changed the ajax call to GET, but still no help.  Using Firefox to see if it gives more info, but that has not given me anything either.  There is a issue with PHP or the server getting the information as i tried a simple one that does work with jquery, but failed in PHP, so it must have something to do with how the info is being asked.  Think I may change it to google rather than leaflet, as this is over a days work :(

Comment: I have managed to get over the XMLHTTP issue, but with your code it comes back with null.

Comment: Okay, I am not getting the data, but still says the object is invalid. I will edit my post to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

From your edited information - using that JS, that PHP but **without** the `json_encode`, that works fine here, fetching and displaying the boundary. You do not need to encode the JSON further, it is already JSON when you fetch it from the server, you are just proxying it through.